# Implementing Binary search tree using array in C

Tags: arrays, c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a binary search tree using a 1-D array. I'm familiar with the fact that the left node will be `parent*2+1` and right node will be `parent*2+2`. I am using this concept to write the insertion function here:

```c
int* insert(int tree[], int element){
    int parent=0;
    if(tree[parent]=='\0'){
        tree[parent]=element;
        return tree;
    }
    else{
        if(element<tree[parent]){
            parent=parent*2+1;
            tree[parent]=insert(tree[parent], element);  
        }
        else{
            parent=parent*2+2;
            tree[parent]=insert(tree[parent], element);
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

However, I'm quite sure this won't work, since I'm passing an element of the array into the `insert()` function while recursing, when it actually needs an array. I'm not sure how to go about it. Do I replace the return type from `int*` to `int`? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why are you using a character constant `'\0'` for a tree with `int` values?  You should use some special integer value, like `-1` or `0`.  Also, it makes no sense to recurse, nor does it make any sense to try to assign the returned pointer value (an `int *`) to a tree node (an `int`).  Delete the recursive calls, and wrap the whole thing in a loop.  The function doesn't need to return anything, since it's never going to return anything other than the `tree` value that was passed to it.

Comment: @TomKarzes so you mean to say I traverse throughout the tree, using a loop, and insert the element wherever necessary?

Comment: Sure.  The only reason to recurse is you have some state that needs to be kept upon return from the recursive call, which you don't since you never go back up the tree, only down.  As soon as you insert the value, you're done.

Comment: The whole reason for storing the parent pointer explicitly is to avoid the slow & dangerous recursion. And I say parent pointer because it would by much more intuitive to use a pointer instead of some manual index calculation scheme.

Answer (score 0):

> the fact that the left node will be parent*2+1 and right node will be parent*2+2

That's correct. You want to use the array index like

```
                        0
                       / \
                      /   \
                     /     \
                    /       \
                   1         2
                  / \       / \
                 /   \     /   \
                3     4   5     6
```

But your recursion is **not** doing that.

You always do `int parent=0;` so you have no knowledge of the real array index and consequently, you access the wrong array elements.

For instance:

When you pass `tree[2]` you really want the function to use either `tree[5]` or `tree[6]` in the next recursive call. However, since you start by setting `parent` to zero, your next recursive call will us either `tree[3]` or `tree[4]`.

**Conclusion** If you want to use recursion, you need to track the actual array index of the current node. Simply passing a pointer to the current node is **not** sufficient.

Instead your code could be:

```
int insert(int* tree, unsigned current_idx, int element){
    if (current_idx >= ARRAY_SIZE) return -1;

    if(tree[current_idx]=='\0'){
        tree[current_idx]=element;
        return 0;
    }

    if(element<tree[current_idx]){
        return insert(tree, 2*current_idx + 1, element);  
    }

    return insert(tree, 2*current_idx + 2, element);  
}
```

That said - you should also spend some time considering whether recursion is really a good solution for this task.

Without recursion you can do:

```
int insert(int* tree, int element){
    unsigned current_idx = 0;

    while (1)
    {    
       if (current_idx >= ARRAY_SIZE) return -1;

       if(tree[current_idx]=='\0'){
            tree[current_idx]=element;
            return 0;
        }

        if(element<tree[current_idx]){
            current = 2*current_idx + 1;
        }
        else {
            current = 2*current_idx + 2;
        }    
    }
}
```

As you can see the recursive approach didn't give you anything. Instead it made things worse...

Comment: Recursion is utterly unnecessary and inappropriate for this problem.  It doesn't simplify it, and the stack isn't needed.

Comment: @TomKarzes Fully agree. This answer is telling OP what is wrong with the current algo. Hopefully OP can use that to find a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid recursion and do it iteratively. Note `tree` is actually an integer array of size `size`. In the function `insert()` we pass a pointer to the array. Assuming the array is initialized with `0`s:

```
void insert(int* tree, int size, int element)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < size)
    {
        if (tree[pos])
        {
            if (tree[pos] < element)
                pos = 2 * pos + 2;  // right
            else if (tree[pos] && tree[pos] > element)
                pos = 2 * pos + 1;  // left
        }
        else
        {
            tree[pos] = element;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insert(int* tree, int size, int element)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < size)
    {
        if (tree[pos])
        {
            if (tree[pos] < element)
                pos = 2 * pos + 2;  // right
            else if (tree[pos] && tree[pos] > element)
                pos = 2 * pos + 1;  // left
        }
        else
        {
            tree[pos] = element;
            return;
        }
    }
}

void print(int* tree, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", tree[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int tree[100] = {0};
    const int tsize = 100;
    
    // print first 20 elements
    print(tree, 20);
    
    insert(tree, tsize, 2);
    insert(tree, tsize, 3);
    insert(tree, tsize, 5);
    insert(tree, tsize, 1);
    insert(tree, tsize, 4);
    
    print(tree, 20);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: If you inside the loop started by doing `if (!tree[pos]) {tree[pos] = element; return;}` the whole `if-else` would be simpler.

Comment: Yeah, we can do that as well :-)